# Managed Service Identity not working as expected in Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-keyvault, azure-managed-identity

I have started with the basic PowerShell http trigger template to retrieve a secret string from Azure Key Vault. I set up the function and key vault exactly as described here:

https://medium.com/statuscode/getting-key-vault-secrets-in-azure-functions-37620fd20a0b

And set up the system assigned identity referencing this documentation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=dotnet#add-a-system-assigned-identity

However there is a new section not mentioned above located in the Identity panel below the status toggle called: "Permissions: Azure Role Assignments":

[image]

With out something set in the Azure Role Assignments the function does not appear to work. Setting this section to use "Reader" from the Key Vault resource type is not enough to get it work retrieve the secret either. Adding "Contributor" under the resource type "Subscription" has enough permissions, but I don't know what is the correct amount of permissions to only provide the level of access to only get the secret.

Can anyone elaborate on this setting and let me know what is the proper way to configure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is setup an Access Policy in your Key Vault listing the permissions (GET/LIST) for the managed identity. Here's a gif showing how to do it:

[image]

Comment: You just listed the url I referenced in the question. That has already been done and the Azure Role Assignments are not mentioned in it either.

Comment: I do exactly what is described in the article. In fact, I did it this morning, works fine and no need to specify roles. I guess you're doing something wrong

Comment: I indeed have get and list referenced already. Without having a permission listed in Azure Role Assignments I have a red "X" beside my key vault reference in the application settings. Do you have a Azure Role Assignments section listed in your "System assigned" Identity section?

Comment: Do you have the Azure Role Assignments section to assign roles?

Comment: Oh well guess I'll just use it the way I have it.

Comment: Well I take that back! I'm not sure what happened or what I screwed up initially but starting over fresh with a C# function instead of a powershell exactly as the blog laid out has the function and permissions behaving as expected... thanks for hanging in there with me!